# GPU fallen off the bus, on idle

Tags: linux-kernel, acpi

In two servers I have, one with RTX2080Ti and another with RTX3080, both of the two severs running as expected on old systems! Centos 7 or 8, running recent system (Centos 9), then the severs keep freezing when idle, the log says "GPU fallen off the bus"!

I'm hundred percent sure it's not a power issue, but it seems that when the machine in idle and the idle driver in the kernel starts doing its job, the board doesn't give the card the enough power to function as expected (I'm improvising!)...

Compiling and running recent kernel on the same old OS (which used to work fine), the issue occurs with the updated kernel... so, I suspected the recent kernels have a bug...

OK, now I decided to run the old kernel (the same version that used to work fine) on a recent OS (Centos 9), I was surprised that the issue is happening...

So, I'm confused! If it's an OS issue, then why the old OS that used to work, has failed when I updated the kernel?!
And if it's a kernel issue, then why the old kernel which used to work fine, fails on the updated OS!!

**NOW, here is the question...
What are the dependencies or libraries that lies between the kernel and the OS when the system goes idle?! As far as I understand, this is the kernel job!**

One more important thing to mention, disabling the cpu idle driver and using the ACPI driver (by idle=nomwait kernel option on boot) fixes the problem, but the system becomes relatively loud and the fans speed relatively high when no load or over heat!

Comment: 1. Reseat the GPU. 2. Replace the PSU with a more powerful one. 3. If nothing helps, ask here https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-graphics/linux/148

Comment: Try to reduce the power consumption, e.g. with `nvidia-smi --power-limit=200`. This worked for me, showing me that my PSU wasn't suitable. Maybe, it helps you too.

Comment: non of these would resolve the problem, as I mentioned, the system works perfect on overload and high power consumption, but it fails when in idle and nothing is happening.
It's something related to power management by the system, it's like it's throttles down the power more than what's acceptable by the GPU when the workstation in idle.
I found a workaround that to disable intel power manager and rely ACPI by using the kernel boot option idle=nomwait but this is making the workstation more noisy and obviously consuming more power